# Response status 301 when making call to web service

Tags: flutter

I need to parse a JSON string receive from a web service.

And this is the function used to get the response.

```
 Future<void> obtenerUsuario() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    var url = Constantes.flutterAPI + "login_user.php";
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "email": controlUsuario.text,
      "password": controlContrasena.text
    });

    print("respuesta :" + response.body);

    print("response status code ${response.statusCode}");

    final Map parsed = json.decode(response.body);



    if (parsed.containsKey('email')) {
      print(parsed['email'].toString());

      setState(() {
       // isLoading = false;
      });

   //   Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
     //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => HomeScreen()));
    } else {

      setState(() {
      //  isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

I am getting following responses printed out:

```
print("respuesta :" + response.body);

flutter: respuesta :<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.labelconcierge.com/app/flutter_api/login_user.php">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>


print("response status code ${response.statusCode}");

flutter: response status code 301
```

And when executing the call using Postman, I am getting the output:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "email": "modestovasco@gmail.com",
    "imagen": "RHxzlhmifoto.jpeg",
    "nombre": "Modesto",
    "apellidos": "Vasco Fornas",
    "activo": "1",
    "token_firebase": ""
}
```

I need your help to make it working as it should.
Please tell me if the problem lies in the server or in the app code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service doesn't accept a POST body, it receives parameters via the URL. So your answer would look like this:

```
  Uri url = Uri.parse('https://www.labelconcierge.com/app/flutter_api/login_user.php?email=modestovasco@gmail.com&password=12345678');
  await http.post(url).then((response) {
    print("response:" + response.body);
  }).catchError((error) {
    print(error);
  });
```

And as good practice you should wrap your http calls in `then()` and `catch()` functions.

Comment: The error message is gone, thank you. But now I am getting: [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".

Comment: Apologies, Flutter doesn't automatically encode JSON, updated answer.

Comment: now, using your last proposal the error is thrown agein

Comment: do you have control over the API?

Comment: not working either

Comment: it is not an API, it is a PHP script, I can show it to you

Comment: or you can get the URL if needed, what you prefer

Comment: Maybe update your original post with the PHP, then others may spot something as well. Assuming Postman works, it may be something to do with the http client or the PHP script. I avoid using the built in http client, and opt for the [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) Package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244201/discussion-between-mvasco-and-jackson-lee).